# Create an CSS3 animation that starts after X seconds

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Im trying to create an animation for a "help window". I would like it to start or have the the image/animation after X seconds, but am having issues as the animation-delay property isn't applicable here as it pauses the still image before playing it.

Any ideas for webkits or properties to try here?

See link here;
http://hardystewartdesign.com/dist/project.html

```
    .hello {
    width: 211px;
    height: 115px;
    background: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 3s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: -300px;}
    to {left: 0px;}

}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: -300px;}
    to {left: 0;}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with giving it initial `left: -300px;` and then use `animation-delay: 2s;`? http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/xtu7cnoj/

Comment: Perfect. Great work around!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change `left: 0` to `left: -300px` in the `.hello` class

Comment: This is a great work around, and hides the animation delay property. Thanks!